# How to secure video url using laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, video

I am developing a E-Learning website which currently has video courses.

Every course has about 5-10 pre-recorded videos and all courses are paid.
Currently we are showing the videos using html5 video, and we are loading the videos using a url simiular to this:
http://ourwebsite.com/course/video/thisvideo.mp4

Now it is very easy to inspect element then open the file url in another window and download it by pressing CTRL+S or such.

What and how would I as secure as possible get the video? I have read about temporary URLs, but haven't found any documentation on how to do so in Laravel.

Does anyone know how to do this? And if so, could you please let me know how!

I assume that using some kind of token would be best.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways maybe you can do or more secured ways to prevent the users from accessing your videos .
one is using **htaccess**
if you want to block direct access to the whole Video folder, you can put a **.htaccess** file in that folder that contains just:

```
deny from all
```

That way you cannot open any file from that folder, but you can include them in php without any problems.

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score -1):

you dont store the videos in a publicly accessible location. Instead you store it somewhere outside of public reach, and fetch it with php. It also depends on whether you want to be downloading this file to the users machine, or are they just streaming it in the browser?